# group by where optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, group-by, where-clause

A query like this:

```
select * from employe_info 
where id in 
( 
    select max(id) 
    from employe_info
    where date < '2016-02-01' 
    group by employe_id 
) 
and `level` = 1 
limit 10
```

`employe_info` has one million rows. I want to query most recent `employe_info` then filter. Is there any way to optimize or a new table design?

Here is the simple table create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `employe` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `employe_info` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employe_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `level` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_employe` (`employe_id`),
  KEY `date_index` (`date`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_employe` FOREIGN KEY (`employe_id`) REFERENCES `employe` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

employe's level is changing with date. A employe has multi level values. So I want to query employe's most recent level before a date.

```
INSERT INTO `employe` (`name`, `address`) VALUES ('joe', 'joe address');

INSERT INTO `employe` (`name`, `address`) VALUES ('mads', 'mads address');

INSERT INTO `employe` (`name`, `address`) VALUES ('max', 'max address');


INSERT INTO `employe_info` (`employe_id`, `level`, `date`) VALUES ('1', '1', '2016-01-01');

INSERT INTO `employe_info` (`employe_id`, `level`, `date`) VALUES ('2', '1', '2016-01-02');

INSERT INTO `employe_info` (`employe_id`, `level`, `date`) VALUES ('3', '1', '2016-01-03');

INSERT INTO `employe_info` (`employe_id`, `level`, `date`) VALUES ('1', '2', '2015-01-01');

INSERT INTO `employe_info` (`employe_id`, `level`, `date`) VALUES ('2', '3', '2015-10-02');

INSERT INTO `employe_info` (`employe_id`, `level`, `date`) VALUES ('3', '4', '2015-08-03');

INSERT INTO `employe_info` (`employe_id`, `level`, `date`) VALUES ('1', '6', '2015-06-01');

INSERT INTO `employe_info` (`employe_id`, `level`, `date`) VALUES ('2', '2', '2015-09-02');

INSERT INTO `employe_info` (`employe_id`, `level`, `date`) VALUES ('3', '4', '2015-06-03');

INSERT INTO `employe_info` (`employe_id`, `level`, `date`) VALUES ('1', '1', '2015-07-01');

INSERT INTO `employe_info` (`employe_id`, `level`, `date`) VALUES ('2', '1', '2015-10-02');

INSERT INTO `employe_info` (`employe_id`, `level`, `date`) VALUES ('3', '1', '2015-11-03');
```

Comment: select * from employe_info where id in ( select max(id) from employe_info where date < '2016-02-01' group by employe_id ) and level = 1 limit 10     you can use my insert data,you can see query result is 3 rows(not a row),I change the date to '2016-02-01'.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your query is wrong. It has at least 3 errors:

1) Two `where` in first query

```
   select * from employe_info 
   where id in ( ..) 
   where level = 1 
   limit 10
```

2) You are using `group by` before `where`

```
  select max(id) 
  from employe_info 
  group by employe_id where date < '2016-01-01'
```

3) In one query you are using `limit 10` and this query base on query with `max(id)` which  will return only one row.

Next, your query is totally strange and can 100% be replaced with more efficient one.

Here is explain of toy query:

```
mysql> explain SELECT
    ->     *
    -> FROM
    ->     employe_info
    -> WHERE
    ->     id IN (SELECT
    ->             MAX(id)
    ->         FROM
    ->             employe_info
    ->         WHERE
    ->             date < '2016-01-02'
    ->         GROUP BY employe_id)
    ->         AND level = 1
    -> LIMIT 10;
+----+--------------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table        | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | employe_info | ALL   | NULL          | NULL       | NULL    | NULL |    3 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | employe_info | range | date_index    | date_index | 4       | NULL |    1 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+--------------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And we can see that it makes two query( query and subquery ).
Query do not use index and subquery uses `index` but also uses `temporary` and `filesort` and this is quite slow way.
Here is result on you query:

Data insertion:

```
INSERT INTO `employe` (`name`, `address`) VALUES ('joe', 'joe address');
INSERT INTO `employe` (`name`, `address`) VALUES ('mads', 'mads address');
INSERT INTO `employe` (`name`, `address`) VALUES ('max', 'max address');
INSERT INTO `employe_info` (`employe_id`, `level`, `date`) VALUES ('1', '1', '2016-01-01');
INSERT INTO `employe_info` (`employe_id`, `level`, `date`) VALUES ('2', '1', '2016-01-02');
INSERT INTO `employe_info` (`employe_id`, `level`, `date`) VALUES ('3', '1', '2016-01-03');
```

Here is result on you query:

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     *
    -> FROM
    ->     employe_info
    -> WHERE
    ->     id IN (SELECT
    ->             MAX(id)
    ->         FROM
    ->             employe_info
    ->         WHERE
    ->             date < '2016-01-02'
    ->         GROUP BY employe_id)
    ->         AND level = 1
    -> LIMIT 10;
+----+------------+-------+------------+
| id | employe_id | level | date       |
+----+------------+-------+------------+
|  1 |          1 |     1 | 2016-01-01 |
+----+------------+-------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

My suggestion is to use my more simpler query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    employe_info
WHERE
    `date` < '2016-01-02'
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You can see that it will return same result as yours :

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     *
    -> FROM
    ->     employe_info
    -> WHERE
    ->     `date` < '2016-01-02'
    -> ORDER BY `date` DESC
    -> LIMIT 1;
+----+------------+-------+------------+
| id | employe_id | level | date       |
+----+------------+-------+------------+
|  1 |          1 |     1 | 2016-01-01 |
+----+------------+-------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And  lets check `explain` of new query

```
mysql> explain SELECT
    ->     *
    -> FROM
    ->     employe_info
    -> WHERE
    ->     `date` < '2016-01-02'
    -> ORDER BY `date` DESC
    -> LIMIT 1;
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | employe_info | range | date_index    | date_index | 4       | NULL |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

So this query uses index and no file sort and temp table so its much efficient.

In Addition I would like suggest to switch to [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html) in future after you will reach 5 -10 rows millions for now this should work fine .

Also you can change `date` column to `bigint`and use timestamp as date if its subtable for you .

**UPDATE**

> . I want to query employe list which matches i gived date and level.
>   Not just a most recent employe. it is the employe list that matches
>   the date and level. then limit.

So you need and one more condition to the query.
Whole query will looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    employe_info
WHERE
    `date` < '2016-01-02' AND `level` = 1
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 1


mysql>    SELECT
    ->         *
    ->     FROM
    ->         employe_info
    ->     WHERE
    ->         `date` < '2016-01-02' AND `level` = 1
    ->     ORDER BY `date` DESC
    ->     LIMIT 1;
+----+------------+-------+------------+
| id | employe_id | level | date       |
+----+------------+-------+------------+
|  1 |          1 |     1 | 2016-01-01 |
+----+------------+-------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

```
mysql> explain
    -> SELECT
    ->     *
    -> FROM
    ->     employe_info
    -> WHERE
    ->     `date` < '2016-01-02' AND `level` = 1
    -> ORDER BY `date` DESC
    -> LIMIT 1;
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | employe_info | range | date_index    | date_index | 4       | NULL |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I give my table create statement.

Comment: I sorry I make a mistake in edit sql. I have changed it. I add some data, you can know what i mean.   level is employe's evaluation, maybe change once a month(not just 1), it will go from a up/down/up. so the employe list will show the level of the employe before a date(mybe now) and can query by date.

Comment: @wanghao your new changed does not change mostly any thing

Comment: I add some other data to employe_info.you can try my sql. Every employe has many info rows. I want to query employe list which matches i gived date and level. Not just a most recent employe. it is the employe list that matches the date and level. then limit.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want the employee info, but only for those who have a level 1 entry when it is the most recent.   Since your query is nested, it APPEARS a person could have one date a level 1, but a newer date within time requirement is a level 2.  Is this assessment accurate and would disqualify the person from being included in the final output?

Instead of having 3 individual indexes, you would be better off having a single composite index of all parts to optimize the query.  If you are only concerned with level 1 entries regardless of he date, then having that in the index would help more.

That said, and my FIRST impression of your query I would have an index on (employe_id, date, id ) since you want the max ID for each employee.  If you ONLY care about level 1 entries, I would have the index on (level, employe_id, date, id )

Can you please clarify the context of the "level"?  Does it ever go up/down or only or is 1 the top-level and all else is a lower-level?  Does it ever go from a up/down/up or only ever keeps getting close to 1?

Comment: level is employe's evaluation, maybe change once a month(not just 1), it will go from a up/down/up. so the employe list will show the level of the employe before a date(mybe now) and can query by date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
select * from employe_info where date < '2016-02-01' group by employe_id ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10;
```